# How to view redis json data in my template view python django

Tags: python, json, django, redis

Question how can I get redis json data to show up in my template? For some reason I can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Here is what I have so far my json data is getting saved to redis correctly but I still can't figure out how to show it in my template. So for obj.customer_name I want it to come from redis and iterate through the json data for my template.

## views.py

```
def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    #obj = Customer.objects.all()
    cust = Customer.objects.all()
    da = serializers.serialize('json', cust, fields=('customer_id', 'customer_name'))
    r_conn = redis.StrictRedis(host='172.16.1.98', port=6379, db=1)
    r_conn.set('dimcert_cust', da)
    cust_cache = r_conn.get('dimcert_cust')
    obj = json.load(cust_cache)


    return render(
        request,
         'app/index.html',
         {
            'title':'Home Page',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
            'obj': obj,
         }
    )
```

## home.html template

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Customers</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">


    <div style="width: 40%; float:left">
        {% for obj in obj.all %}
          <h3> {{obj.customer_name}} </h3>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>      
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

## Here is my model.py with Customer class

```
from django.db import models
import json

class Customer(models.Model):
  objects = models.Manager()
  customer_id = models.IntegerField()
  customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  created_at = models.DateField
  updated_at = models.DateField
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are converting the json to a dictionary with by doing `obj = json.load(cust_cache)` So in your template, what you should have is something like this:

```
{% for key, values in obj.items %}

   <h3>{{ key }}</h3>
   {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

As a footnote, may I point out that [redis hashes](http://redis.io/commands#hash) is a better way to store your data.

Comment: Glad to have been of help.